# Mean reducer changes scale in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, scale

I am working with NOAA CFSV2 data trying to get an Image that is a one-year average of an ImageCollection. However, in the process the scale of an image changes:

```
var uv = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H')
  .select('Downward_Long-Wave_Radp_Flux_surface_6_Hour_Average')
  .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31');

// reduce the image collection to one image by summing all rasters within a given year:
var muv = uv.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

//Checking the scale:
var scale_uv = uv.first().projection().nominalScale();
print('Scale of uv', scale_uv);
//Scale of uv: 34771.29356168821
var scale_muv = muv.projection().nominalScale();
print('Scale of muv', scale_muv);
//Scale of muv: 111319.49079327357
```

Does anyone know why this happens and what is the way to avoid that?